# How to find 'user_hash' on telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to use telethon and telebot to send notification from my code in python.
I have configureted everythings, but the code ask me the following:

`receiver = InputPeerUser('user_id', 'user_hash')`

I fund user_id, but I don't understand where I could catch my user_hash.

Comment: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a 'user_hash', just enter 0.

I.e.:

```
userid=555555555
userhash=0

receiver=InputPeerUser(userid, userhash)
```

> For those requests having a “limit” parameter, you can often set it to
> zero to signify “return default amount”. This won’t work for all of
> them though, for instance, in “messages.search” it will actually
> return 0 items.

Reference:
https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/advanced-usage/accessing-the-full-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You must have an open dialogue with that user. Or you received a message from him. When all the dialogs are loaded, the information of that user comes with it.